# MySQL Table in use and doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

i don't know why
i always get this kind of error everytime.
one of my table in database

```
in use
```

it is always happening everytime i close mysql and my project. last time i open the table it is still exist.

i tried the following

```
CHECK TABLE table_name;
```

and tried to

```
REPAIR TABLE table_name
```

and it shows like this

```
+-----------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                  |
+-----------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| pk.produk | repair | Error    | Table 'pk.produk' doesn't exist in engine |
| pk.produk | repair | status   | Operation failed                          |
+-----------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

can you help me to show this? i really appreciate !

Comment: Restart mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

```
REPAIR TABLE table_name
```

command should repair and fix the `in use` problem you are facing.

The only thing that seems to me as message suggests

> Table 'pk.produk' doesn't exist in engine

is, the schema `pk`

Make sure you are on correct schema. If not then run,

```
USE schema_name;
```

And then again run the repair command.